# Why does Xcode auto-completion not work and keep showing errors?

Tags: xcode, import, autocomplete, code-completion

I am new to Xcode. After a few days of "normal" use, where I didn't get any problems of any kind, Xcode stopped working properly.

The auto code completion now gives me only the methods ("M"). If, for example, I'm in "ViewController.swift" and write `if ...`, an error appears and does not show me the hint. It seems as if it doesn't "import" the right libraries.

[img1 http://cl.ly/image/1u3J120y3A1J/Image%202015-01-22%20at%207.32.57%20PM.png](http://cl.ly/image/1u3J120y3A1J/Image%202015-01-22%20at%207.32.57%20PM.png)

[img2 http://cl.ly/image/0r1a1x210U17/Image%202015-01-22%20at%207.33.13%20PM.png](http://cl.ly/image/0r1a1x210U17/Image%202015-01-22%20at%207.33.13%20PM.png)

[image: img3]

Comment: I don't believe an if statement is valid there, which is why the autocomplete and compiler are blowing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart Xcode. Deleting the Derived Data Xcode folder should fix the issue. You can do this by heading to `~/Library/Developer/XCode/DerivedData` and deleting all the subfolders in it.

By the way, in the first screenshot you **can't** use an `if` statement that way (outside any function). So this may not be a problem of Xcode.

I am seeing your second screenshot: you can't type `init`. It doesn't make sense.

In the third screenshot you are trying to `import` something, but you must import modules outside any class.

Comment: The "If statement" was for example. Any text I write it just hints me "M" completions

Comment: Did you try restarting Xcode and deleting the DerivedData's subfolders?

Comment: Yes, I also tried delete and reinstall Xcode 3 times

Comment: In the first screenshot you seem to be typing `init`, which doesn't make sense. Does the code work alone? I mean, when you create an app, do you get any kind of errors?

Comment: No errors when i start a new project. Neither if i write inside `override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()` (inside that all works great)

Comment: That's good. In this image (http://i.stack.imgur.com/ofY5E.png) you are trying to import something but `import` statements should only be typed outside any class.

Comment: This means Xcode isn't the problem. Try, for example, typing this code, inside the class, but outside the `func viewDidLoad()`: `func Hello() { println("Hello! Xcode is working fine")}`. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @CeceXX import is outside the class. and belong the init... you should use convenience initializers... May i think, that you aren't such deep in swift yet? I'm not really good in it too :-( :D

Comment: @DanielBocksteger what do you mean?

Comment: @CeceXX Thanks for your support, now everyone has settled. Before even declare a "IBOutlet" gave error. I deleted "Derive Date" but kept giving me error, maybe because I had not restarted the mac. After reboot now everything works! I'm so happy ;)